# Wrong date on setting Calendar timeZone to UTC

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nscalendar

Allover the app I use Date objects that when I NSLog the value it shows me:

2020-05-24 22:00:00 +0000

Which I think locally means the 25th (- 1 for summer, -1 for timezone). I want to do some Calendar date comparisons:

```
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")!
// In order to have start on Monday
calendar.firstWeekday = 2
```

Using this calendar, lets say I want to get the starting date of current week:

```
extension Date
{
    var startOfWeek: Date {
        return Calendar.gregorian.date(from: Calendar.gregorian.dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: self))!
    }
}
```

If I NSLog:

```
Date().startOfWeek
```

It will show me:

2020-05-25 00:00:00 +0000

If I disable the timeZone line on Calendar, it shows me:

2020-05-24 22:00:00 +0000

I always thought the second one is the correct UTC version. Am I wrong? Because I thought all core data dates, all dates are in the 2nd version. In short: If I set Calendar to UTC, my date comparissons are wrong. If I don't they are good. And all this time dates are in UTC.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrong because CoreData dates are not affected by TimeZone. Dates are dates. Think of them as numeric values. When you translate that value to a date and hour then, and only then, the TimeZone is applied.

In your example everything is correct. For a calendar whose TimeZone is UTC, 2020-05-25 00:00:00 +0000 is the beginning of the week. If you use other TimeZone values (for example the default value from Locale) then the your week start at 2020-05-24 22:00:00 +0000. That means that in your TimeZone the hour is 2020-05-25 00:00:00.